# flyway not picking up migrations when used from docker-compose

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, flyway

I have the following service in my docker-compose.yml file:

```
flyway:
    image: boxfuse/flyway:latest-alpine
    command: -url=jdbc:postgresql://yurldb:5432/yurldb -schemas=public -user=postgres -password=somepassword migrate
    networks:
      - yunet
    volumes:
      - ./flyway:/flyway/sql
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - yurldb
```

And I have just one migration in my resources package:

[image]

When I run the service with docker compose (docker-compose up -d --build flyway)
The flyway creates the flyway_schema_history table but doesn't create the table defined in the migration. If i check the logs i see this message:

> Flyway Community Edition 5.2.4 by Boxfuse Database:
>   jdbc:postgresql://yurldb:5432/yurldb (PostgreSQL 10.13) Successfully
>   validated 0 migrations (execution time 00:00.011s) Current version of
>   schema "public": << Empty Schema >> Schema "public" is up to date. No
>   migration necessary.

The migration is not triggered. Why is that? I am not sure what I am missing. I have the migrations in the correct package and also the SQL inside is correct(else there would be some sort of syntax error). It just doesn't detect that migration. Any idea?

**update**
I just noticed that when i run that command a little directory is created in the package structure. Not sure what it is:

[image]

I am also adding another picture to show also the overall structure of the project:

[image]

**update 2**
Using the volume mapping `./src/main/resources/db.migration:/flyway/sql` generated an additional directory in my package structure:

[image]

Comment: How does mapping `./flyway` and `resource catalog` look like?

Comment: @ŁukaszOlszewski I am not sure I fully understand your question but I just wrote an update. A little directory is created when I dun docker compose. It has a little gray symbol(not sure what it means). Also I am not sure what the resource catalog is. Can you explain me please?

Comment: You need to map `resource catalog` do docker container. Try this `./src/main/resource /db.migration:/flyway/sql` in your docker compose file.

Comment: @ŁukaszOlszewski Was there a typo on that you just sent? I tried `./src/main/resources/db.migration:/flyway/sql` but it didn't work 
Also notice that a new was created under resources with the gray symbol(I added a pic)

Comment: yep, just try to add `/` at end of path. eg. `./src/main/resources/db.migration/:/flyway/sql/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your mapping to this `./src/main/resources/db/migration:/flyway/sql`

Using `db.migration` causes Docker to create with that name, Intellij just shows the directory `db/migration` like a package name `db.dmigration` if the db directory has only directories in it.

Comment: That's correct I forgot that db.migration is actually a directory inside another directory.
I tried `./src/main/resources/db/migration/:/flyway/sql/` and it worked. Thanks