# Flyway can't find migrations when database is run on docker container

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, database-migration, flyway

I have been following [this tutorial](https://writeitdifferently.com/postgresql/flyway/2020/03/15/running-postgresql-and-flyway-with-docker-compose.html) trying to set up a database using flyway migration scripts. The only difference with the tutorial is that I have been trying to use it in a Spring Boot application. For some reason, when I run "docker-compose up" I always get the the following logging in my terminal.

> flyway_1    | Flyway Community Edition 7.5.3 by Redgate flyway_1    |
> Database: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/db-name (PostgreSQL 12.2)
> flyway_1    | Successfully validated 0 migrations (execution time
> 00:00.041s) flyway_1    | WARNING: No migrations found. Are your
> locations set up correctly? flyway_1    | Current version of schema
> "public": << Empty Schema >> flyway_1    | Schema "public" is up to
> date. No migration necessary.

However, I have a migration script under src/main/resources/db/migration. I am not sure why it is not able to find it, as it seems that is where flyway is supposed to look for them by default.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  flyway:
    image: flyway/flyway:7.5.3
    command: -configFiles=/flyway/conf/flyway.config -locations=filesystem:/flyway/sql -connectRetries=60 migrate
    volumes:
    - ${PWD}/src/main/java/resources/db/migration
    - ${PWD}/docker-flyway.config:/flyway/conf/flyway.config
    depends_on:
    - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12.2
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=example-username
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
    - POSTGRES_DB=db-name
```

And here is my docker-flyway.config file.

```
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/db-name
flyway.user=example-username
flyway.password=pass
flyway.baselineOnMigrate=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I had one of the volume mappings written incorrectly in my docker-compose.yml file. I don't exactly understand the mapping itself, but after copying what was in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244176/flyway-not-picking-up-migrations-when-used-from-docker-compose?rq=1) it ran the migration script properly.

Answer (score 1):

The Flyway files need to have the .sql extension. Mentioned here: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/concepts/migrations#naming

Comment: I tried adding that extension, but unfortunately I am still getting the same thing logging in my terminal.